# Making a check-in counter for an IPhone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am new to IPhone programming and I want to make an IPhone application where users check-in to increase a counter (i.e: When you you check-in with the places application you increase the number of people that are at that place so when others login they can also see how many people are there as well). My question is where do I store a such a counter like that for the application ?

Comment: what I can gauge from your question is that people will login from different iphones , if this is the point then you will need a server and online database where you can store the checked in user count

Comment: Yes you are right.  Do you suggest any service for this purpose ? Does iOS provide some service with an API for this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a singleton to keep a unique track of the counter. See [link](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/).

Comment: I see but as far as I understood this is a local solution. What I am wondering is where I can store this singleton so that its updated online all around the world? Does iOS provide something like a server API to store the app data in the cloud ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use foursquare APIs for this they have well documented services for checkin and various other services